# Is this proof on neighborhoods in a increasing sequence of closed sets, incorrect?

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

In my topology course, the professor mentions the following theorem:

> **Theorem**. Let $X = \bigcup_{i\ge 0} X_i$ where each $X_i$ is a closed subspace of $X_{i+1}$ and $X$ is given the coherent topology with respect to the family of inclusions $X_i\hookrightarrow X$. Suppose $B\subset W\subset X$ are such that for each $i$, $W\cap X_i$ is a neighborhood of $B\cap X_i$ in $X_i$. Then $W$ is a neighborhood of $B$ in $X$.

Before mentioning his proof, I mention the following lemma which he uses (I have no issues understanding the proof of this lemma, so I am just stating it):

> **Lemma**. Let $Y\subset X$ be a closed subset. Let $A$ be any subset. Let $V$ be an open set in $X$ such that $A\subset V$. Suppose $U$ is an open set in $Y$ such that
> $$A\cap Y\subset U\subset V\cap Y\text.$$
> Then there exists an open set $V'$ in $X$ such that $A\subset V'\subset V$ and $V'\cap Y = U$.

Now, the proof he presents for the theorem:

> **Proof**. We appeal to the lemma with $X = X_{i+1}$, $Y = X_i$, $A = X_i\cap B$, $\color{red}{V = X_i\cap W}$ for each $i$. We then inductively choose open sets $U_i$ in $X_i$ such that $B\cap X_i\subset U_i\subset W\cap X_i$ and such that $U_{i+1}\cap X_i = U_i$. We then put $U = \bigcup_{i\in I} U_i$, and check that
> $$B\subset U\subset W\text.$$
> Also $U$ is open in $X$ by the definition of coherent topology.

**Question:** It is the highlighted part in red that I don't understand. To apply the lemma we must ensure that $V$ is open in $X$ (in the language of the lemma), *i.e.*, $X_i\cap W$ must be open in $X_{i + 1}$. ***How is this guaranteed?***

Further, **if we do assume that $X_i\cap W$'s are open in $X_{i + 1}$'s**, then due to $Xi$'s being nested subspaces, it'll follow that $X_i\cap W$ is open in $W$ and thus by coherency, it trivially follows that $W$ is open in $X$.

Comment: $X_{i}$ is closed in $X_{l+1}$ in a coherent topology [definition in Munkres exercise 9 of section 35]

Comment: @AdityaEkbote Yes, and how does this help?

Comment: I am extremely sorry, I must've misread something or can't recall what I was thinking but I promise to come back with at least a comment. What I am thinking currently is you would want $W$ to be open since since you want $V$ to be open in $X$ i.e $X_{i+1}$ to appeal the lemma I am thinking about $X_i$ being open in $W$ but as I promised I will come back with a comment. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: @AdityaEkbote No worries! And absolutely no need to say sorry. But if $W$ is open, everything becomes trivial!